# Automatically filling field for new list item from page details

Tags: 2010, list, custom-list, list-form, item

I have a 'Issues' list that describes any issues our employees find in a product. Each item added to the list must be associated with a product. To do that, there is currently a look-up to our products list in a column called 'Product Lookup'.

The 'Issues' list appears on every product page. All 26 products have their own unique pages. When an employee adds a new item to the list, is it possible for the list to read information from the page and automatically set the 'Product Lookup' column or another column to the product?

For example, if I were to find an issue with Product XYZ, I would go to the page for Product XYZ and add a new item to the 'Issues' list. When I click "add new item", I would *only* have to describe the issue and *not* have to list Product XYZ as the associated product.

Let me know if you need any more information. The 'Product Lookup' column does *not* need to be a look-up column, that is just the current system. It does, however, need to be sortable. I do **not** want to create an individual 'issues' list for every product, as it is important for our staff to view **all** products and issues at once in one large list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a script editor to set the lookup value using Page Name.

Comment: would the script be on each page? or should I place it 'default edit form' web part for the list?

I'm not familiar with using a script to set the look-up value. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.